# Evaluate the outer integral $\int_0^{2\pi} \int_{\theta_c}^{\pi/2} \cos(\theta)\sin(\theta) d\theta d\phi$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Can anyone please explain how the outer integral is evaluated?

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_{\theta_c}^{\pi/2} \cos(\theta)\sin(\theta) d\theta d\phi$$

My source says $$2\pi\int_{\theta_c}^{\pi/2} \cos(\theta)\sin(\theta) d\theta$$

I don't know how this is done.

Comment: What is $\theta_c$ ?

Comment: @Tuvasbien I just want the outer integral to be evaluated. Updating the question, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the inner integral depends only on $\theta$ and not $\phi$, we can evaluate them independently.

$$\begin{eqnarray}\int_{\theta_c}^{\pi/2}\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)d\theta & = & \left[ -\frac{1}{2}\cos^2(\theta)\right]_{\theta_c}^{\pi/2} \\
& = & \frac{1}{2}\cos^2(\theta_c) \\
\int_0^{2\pi} \int_{\theta_c}^{\pi/2}\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)d\theta d\phi & = & \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2}\cos^2(\theta_c)d\phi \\
& = & \frac{1}{2}\cos^2(\theta_c)\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi \\
& = & \frac{1}{2}\cos^2(\theta_c)\left[ \phi\right]_0^{2\pi} \\
& = & 2\pi \frac{1}{2}\cos^2(\theta_c)
\end{eqnarray}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)$ doesn't depend of $\varphi$ so
$$ \int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\theta_c}^{\pi/2}\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)d\theta d\varphi=2\pi\int_{\theta_c}^{\pi/2}\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)d\theta $$
It is like integrating a constant.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $ \theta_{c}\in\mathbb{R} $, we have : $$ \int_{\theta_{c}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta}=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\theta_{c}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\sin{\left(2\theta\right)}\,\mathrm{d}\theta}=\frac{1}{2}\left[-\frac{\cos{\left(2\theta\right)}}{2}\right]_{\theta_{c}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}=\frac{1+\cos{\left(2\theta_{c}\right)}}{4} $$

Thus, $$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}{\int_{\theta_{c}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta}\,\mathrm{d}\varphi}=\pi\left(\frac{1+\cos{\left(2\theta_{c}\right)}}{2}\right)=\pi\cos^{2}{\theta_{c}} $$